# How to use HOC to assign a value to a component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, parameters, higher-order-components

I'm trying to make an HOC that assign values to the parameter "color" in an icon component in React js.
I have 3 different colors. They come as follow : 
pimary is #f7a014
secondary is #dd8b08
ternary is #56t00

So I can do :

```
<MyComponent color='primary' />
```

Here is my withColor HOC :

```
 import React from 'react';
 import propTypes from 'prop-types';

 function mapColors(color) {
 if (color === 'primary') {
 return '#f8af39';
 }
 if (color === 'secondary') {
 return '#fff';
 }
if (color === 'ternary') {
 return '#004c64';
}}


export const withColor = WrappedComponent => {
const NewComponent = ({ color, ...props }) => (
 <WrappedComponent color={mapColors(color)} {...props} />
  );

  NewComponent.propTypes = {
  color: propTypes.oneOf(['primary', 'secondary', 'ternary']),
 };
  return NewComponent;
  };

  export default withColor;
```

Here is my component with the icon in it :

```
import React from 'react';
import { RequestCloseModal } from 'HOC/connectModals';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import {
  Collapse,
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  ModalFooter,
} from 'reactstrap';
import { ChevronDown, ChevronUp } from 'react-feather';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Industrie from 'components/Icons/Industrie';
import FinancerContainer from 'backoffice/containers/Financer/FinancerContainer';
import withContainer from 'HOC/withContainer';
import withColor from 'HOC/WithColor';

class FinancerMatchingDetails extends RequestCloseModal {
  static propTypes = {
    isOpen: PropTypes.bool,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      collapse: false,
    };
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({ collapse: !this.state.collapse });
  };

  render() {
    const { isOpen } = this.props;
    return (
      <Modal size="xxl" isOpen={isOpen} toggle={this.close}>
        <ModalHeader toggle={this.close}>
              <div className="col-md-3">
                <h4>Some text</h4>
                <p>Some text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h4>Some text</h4>
            {this.state.collapse ? (
              <ChevronUp height={20} onClick={this.toggle} />
            ) : (
              <ChevronDown height={20} onClick={this.toggle} />
            )}
          </div>
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <div className="container">
            <Collapse isOpen={this.state.collapse}>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col">
                        <MyIcon color="primary" />
                    </div>
            </Collapse>
          </div>
        </ModalFooter>
     </Modal>
    );
  }
}

export default compose(withContainer(FinancerContainer), withColor)(
FinancerMatchingDetails,
);
```

I'm new to HOC and can't make it to assign the color primary. Thanks for your help.

Comment: why on earth are you doing this

Comment: why don't you just pass props

Answer (score 1):

You defined HOC but never pass any components through it.
E.g.

```
import withColor from 'HOC/WithColor'; // your HOC
import SomeComponent from 'SomeComponent'; // component that you would like to use with HOC
```

then you need to define a component that is the result of HOC applied to your component:

```
const ColoredComponent = withColor(SomeComponent);
```

and then you can use it as you expected:

```
<ColoredComponent color="primary" />
```